# Nested 'If' statement in jinja 'for' loop

Tags: python, html, for-loop, if-statement, jinja2

I am trying to sneak in an `if`statement within a loop for a jinja template:

```
</table>
<class="container">
<table border ="1">
<caption> BBOXX <caption>
<thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
        <th>CU Serial</th>
        <th>System</th>
        <th>Version</th>
        <th>Enable Status</th>
    </tr>
        {% for d in client_data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ d["serial_number"]}} </td>
            <td>{{ d["hardware_type"]}} </td>
                {% if {{ d["current_enable_flag"]}} == TRUE %}
                    <td> {{ON}} </td>
                {% else %}
                    <td> {{OFF}} </td>
                {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

the error is `TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'`

Where should this `:` be?

Comment: I think you need the `:` after the if statement: `if {{ d["current_enable_flag"]}} == TRUE:`

Comment: @numbermaniac: this isn't Python code, no there is no need to use a `:`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah my mistake, from the tags I thought the "sneaky if statement" must've been Python code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your `if` syntax wrong. You do not need to use `{{ ... }}` to insert a variable, that's only used to interpolate values in the *template output*.

Use

```html
{% if d["current_enable_flag"] == TRUE %}
    <td> {{ON}} </td>
{% else %}
    <td> {{OFF}} </td>
{% endif %}
```

If `d["current_enable_flag"]` is a Python boolean, you can drop the `== TRUE` part altogether.

Demo:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> template = Template('''\
... {% for d in client_data %}
... <tr>
...     <td>{{ d["serial_number"]}} </td>
...     <td>{{ d["hardware_type"]}} </td>
...     {% if d["current_enable_flag"] %}
...         <td> {{ON}} </td>
...     {% else %}
...         <td> {{OFF}} </td>
...     {% endif %}
... </tr>
... {% endfor %}
... ''')
>>> html_rendered = template.render(client_data=[
...     {'serial_number': 42, 'hardware_type': 'foo', 'current_enable_flag': True},
...     {'serial_number': 81, 'hardware_type': 'bar', 'current_enable_flag': False}
... ], ON='ON', OFF='OFF')
>>> print(html_rendered)

<tr>
    <td>42 </td>
    <td>foo </td>

        <td> ON </td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>81 </td>
    <td>bar </td>

        <td> OFF </td>

</tr>
```