# Compare context variable django

Tags: python, django

How can I compare context variable in Django?
I want to compare the name that I have saved in my model with `request.user`

```
{% if user %}
  {% for x in user %}
    {% ifequal x request.user %}
      <h1>working</h1>
    {% else %}
      <h1>false</h1>
    {% endifequal %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I want the following comparison:
`{{x}} == {{request.user}}`

Context dict

```
{"user": Prod.objects.filter().values_list('name', flat=True)}
```

User is here for example `admin` and request.user is also `admin`

My model:

```
class Prod(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwdtv.png)

I am using a context processor in the base.html

```
from farmer_page.models import Prod
def context_variable(request):
    # .values_list('name', flat=True)
    return {"user": Prod.objects.filter()}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested 'If' statement in jinja 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258161/nested-if-statement-in-jinja-for-loop)

Comment: Does Prod table has data related to current logged in user if not {{ request.user.user_name  }} will print nothing.

Comment: ```request.user.username``` worked for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [if template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if) in your templates:

```
{% if x == request.user %}
```

#### Edit

```
{% if user %}
  {% for x in user %}
    {% if x.name == request.user %}
      <h1>working</h1>
    {% else %}
      <h1>false</h1>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Prod contains multiple names like ```admin user1 user2 user3``` so I still need to loop through it?

Comment: Based on what you want to accomplish, you can either loop through it or use [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator) template tag.

Comment: ```{% if user in request.user %}
                            <h1>working</h1>
                            {% else %}
                            <h2>false</h2>
                            {% endif %}``` This is not working I get false

Comment: If you are looking for `request.user` in `user`: {% if request.user in user %}

Comment: Still the same result ```false```

Comment: I found the issue! As mentioned in the last example of [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator), you can check the existence of objects with the **same type** with `in`. So you should use the `for` loop for that.

Comment: ```{% for x in user%}
                                {% if request.user in x %}
                                <h1 class="text-white">working</h1>
                                {% else %}
                                <h1 class="text-white">failed </h1>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}``` Do you mean something like this? It is still not working

Comment: It is actually looping over and I added a picture. ```x.name = Herres1234``` and ```request.user = Herres1234```, but it is still giving false?

Comment: @GigaMeta Based on the picture, I can guess your `user` context variable contains 4 objects, with two that have `name=Herres1234`. So you are looping over those 4 objects and checking whether each of them satisfy the condition. It should give you false for those two objects that have other `name`s.

Comment: No, each user is unique. I first printed ```{{request.user}}``` and then ```{{x.name}}``` to be sure if it is really "matching", but it is still printing out false.

Comment: When I try to print out what you have mentioned so ```{{request.user.first_name}}``` nothing is printing out, but if I use ```{{request.user}}``` I get the user name

Comment: Please check those conditions in the interactive shell to find out whats wrong. I just test that and it worked fine for me. Also check `{% if x.name.username == request.user.username %}` (this should work even if you are not linking the same user in the foreign key)

Comment: Well, it is now working. ```request.user.username``` is returning a string and ```request.user``` not. In your edit it still says ```request.user```. Thats why it wasn't working. Thanks it worked out now.

Answer (score 0):

Context dict:

```
{"user": Prod.objects.filter(condition)}
```

template

```
 {% if request.user in user %}
<h1>success</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>failed</h1>
{% endif %}
```

**---------Edit----------**

Always use related name in Foreign key

```
class Prod(models.Model):
    .
    .
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_name')
```

**views.py**

```
{"user": Prod.objects.filter(condition)}
```

**html template**

```
{% if request.user.user_name in user %}
    <h1>success</h1>
    {% else %}
    <h1>failed</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes I'm doing this but is it not working because user is a queryset?

Comment: @GigaMeta what is model "Prod". Is this for users?

Comment: Prod stands for Products, each "Prod" has a name and I filter them

Comment: @GigaMeta Then this will not work. request.user is current logged in user. It will not match with instance of Product model.

Comment: @GigaMeta Is anything common in Prod model and User model?

Comment: Yes, the names, because I have a foreign key to the User model

Comment: No, it is still not working. When I try to print out ```{{request.user.user_name}}``` It doesnt print anything and if I put it in the if it won't work also.

Comment: @GigaMeta you sure user is logged in? I just tested this my dummy project.

Comment: Yes, the user is logged in because when I do ```{{request.user}}``` I get the user

Comment: @GigaMeta, did you add related_name and makemigrations -> migrate after adding.

Comment: @GigaMeta can show actual views, model and html template which you are trying if you don't mind.